# Spring MVC: How to respond a http request with JSON object and view together?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

It's like user click a link and in the Spring controller class a method will respond to the request with a `JSON` object and also a view name (meaning, it should return but not only a JSON object but also a HTTP view which hold that JSON object, so `@ResponseBody` may not enough)? Do we have to split it up into two methods (one for view and the other for JSON object)? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Normally we have

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someValue")
public @ResponseBody someMethod1(@RequestParam String param){
    .....
    return someJSONObject
}
```

To handle JSON object, and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someValue")
public String someMethod2(@RequestParam String param){
    .....
    return someViewInString;
}
```

To return the view.

How can we combine them together?

Comment: Can't you save the json object as an attribute and reference in your view using `${name_of_json_attr}`? (I guess this may only work if your view is `jsp`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the view with a placeholder for the JSON.

In the controller code, create the JSON programatically, convert it to String format and then put it in the model (let's call it json_string)

In the view there should be a placeholder for the JSON string, something like:

```
<!-- other view stuff -->
var v = ${json_string};
<!-- more view stuff -->
```

Comment: That's good work around. Thank you. So then we still use JSON but it's like a Strin in JSON format from controller?